# sqrt from math.h causes linker error "undefined reference to sqrt" only when the argument is not a constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

I created a small program, as follows:

```
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i; 
    double tmp;
    double xx;

    for(i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
      xx = (double) i + 0.01;

      tmp = sqrt(xx);
      printf("the square root of %0.4f is %0.4f\n", xx,tmp);
      sleep(1);
      xx = 0;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

When I try to compile this with the following command, I get a compiler error.

```
gcc -Wall calc.c -o calc
```

returns:

```
/tmp/ccavWTUB.o: In function `main':
calc.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I replace the variable in the call to sqrt(xx) with a constant like sqrt(10.2), it compiles just fine.  Or, if I explicitly link like the following:

```
gcc -Wall -lm calc.c -o calc
```

It also works just fine.  Can anyone tell me what's causing this?  I've been a C programmer for a long time (and I've written similar small programs using math.h) and I have never seen anything like this.

My version of gcc follows:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$
```

Comment: Does it still need `-lm` if you specify `--std=c99`?

Comment: Yeah. Weird. I also tried using -ansi to the same effect. No-go without -lm

Comment: It's an interesting feature of gcc that you need to explicitly link the maths library - it catches everybody out first time. 
That the compiler can silently replace sqrt(10.2) for you just adds to the fun!

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not a compiler error, it's a linker error.

Comment: A more generic question without the `sqrt(CTE)` observation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248919/c-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-or-other-mathematical-functions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the output of the compiler in the case where you used `sqrt(10.2)`, I'll bet you see that a call to `sqrt()` isn't actually made.

This happens because GCC recognizes several functions that it can treat specially. This gives it the ability to do certain optimizations, in this case [Constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). Such special functions are called [Built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

In the case where it must link to the math library (because you're calling it with a variable), you need to link it explicitly.  Some operating systems/compilers do it for you, which is why you might not have noticed in the past.

Comment: +1 Many systems automatically link against the math library for you.  Some don't.  Yours doesn't.

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that if you take the sqrt of a constant, the result is also a constant, so the compiler does it for you at compile time, leaving no calls to sqrt in the code, so you don't need to link against libm (-lm) at link time.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to try this on my Mac when I get home and see what happens.

Comment: You don't need the `-lm` on a Mac.  Well at least not on the one I'm using now.

Comment: @CarlNorum what's the compiler you're using?

Comment: In 2009 it was probably GCC.