# Why am I getting "undefined reference to sqrt" error even though I include math.h header?

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, libm

I'm very new to C and I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
  double x = 0.5;
  double result = sqrt(x);
  printf("The square root of %lf is %lf\n", x, result);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this with:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

I get an error like this:

```
/tmp/cc58XvyX.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does this happen? Is `sqrt()` not in the `math.h` header file? I get the same error with `cosh` and other trigonometric functions. Why?

Comment: And here is some speculation why about why `libm` isn't linked by default even though it contains part of the standard library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

Comment: It's a duplicate to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5248919/694576

Comment: Is there a reason this doesn't throw an error when using an integer literal? Ie. `sqrt(12345)` compiles fine without `-lm`. Is the compiler doing the math?

Comment: it still doesn't work after I follow the accepted answer, what a tired action for a simple function, but call sqrt() with a exact number still work

Answer (score 256, accepted):

The math library must be linked in when building the executable.  How to do this varies by environment, but in Linux/Unix, just add `-lm` to the command:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lm
```

The math library is named `libm.so`, and the `-l` command option assumes a `lib` prefix and `.a` or `.so` suffix.

Comment: But this is actually weird that after being a standard library it is not linked automatically by the compiler in Linux.

Comment: This comes from many decades ago.  In those days, there were widely used options to link alternate libraries.  One used the coprocessor.  Another implemented the coprocessor calculations in software.  I think I remember a joke library which prompted the computer operator "quick:  what is 3.46 times 67.884?"

Comment: It's worth specifying that `-lm` must be after the source file, otherwise the error is produced anyway.

Answer (score 44):

You need to link the with the `-lm` linker option.

You need to compile as:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lm
```

`gcc` (Not `g++`) historically would not by default include the mathematical functions while linking. It has also been separated from libc onto a separate library libm. To link with these functions you have to advise the linker to include the library `-l` linker option followed by the library name `m` thus `-lm`.
Observe that the order of arguments matter, it does not work if `-lm` is placed immediately after `gcc`.

Answer (score 12):

This is a likely a linker error.
Add the `-lm` switch to specify that you want to link against the standard C math library (`libm`) which has the definition for those functions (the header just has the *declaration* for them - worth looking up the difference.)

Answer (score 6):

Because you didn't tell the linker about location of **math** library. Compile with **gcc test.c -o test -lm**

Answer (score 6):

Add header:

`#include<math.h>`

Note: use abs(), sometimes at the time of evaluation sqrt() can take negative values which leave to domain error.

abs()- provides absolute values;

example, abs(-3) =3

Include -lm at the end of your command during compilation time:

`gcc <filename.extension> -lm`