# Fatal error: modbus.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, makefile, modbus

I'm expecting a lot of difficulties to make my program working with the library libmodbus on Linux.

I've installed libmodbus with the command `sudo make install` and after make but the problem is when I want to link the library in my C program.

My Makefile for now is like:

```
all: test
test: main.o com.o
  gcc main.o com.o -o test

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o

com.o: com.c
    gcc -c com.c -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -Wl,LIBDIR -o com.o

clean:
    rm -rf *o test
```

In my file com.c I include the file modbus.h like this:

```
#include <modbus.h>
```

And I always get the error:

```
fatal error: modbus.h: No such file or directory.
```

If it can help when I did make install, the code return me this:

> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
>   in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
>   specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
>   flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable during execution
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable during linking
> - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
> - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

Comment: See [Compiling a progam that includes `libmodbus` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697543/compiling-a-program-that-includes-libmodbus-in-c) when you get past the hurdles of creating the `main.o` and `com.o` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `modbus.h` is not in the standard include directory.
You should to add the `-I/<includes_path>` flag to gcc options.

I suppose here:

```
gcc -I/<include_dir_path> -c com.c -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -Wl,LIBDIR -o com.o
```

Comment: The problem is that even if do a manual include like -I <includ_dir_path> on the source code I get another error like main.o file not recognized.And I get collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's not that I have another error, it's because I already tried this solution and on google they said that I have to link the makefile with the librairy, not the source code so "-I<include_path_dir" wasn't really useful.

Comment: Ok, but the described in question error is totally preprocessing error and not a linkage error. What error do you have if you give a full path to the header?

Comment: The `-Wl,` options are not material to creating an object file (`com.o`).  They are directives to the linker, which is run when creating the executable.  They'll be needed in the line which currently reads `gcc main.o com.o -o test`.  The `-I` suggestion is 100% correct for creating the object files, though.