# dtest.c:(.text+0xb65): undefined reference to `sqrt'

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, cc

I am trying to install and run a mathematical library called [PDSLin](http://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/pdslin/)   on my ubuntu 16.04 machine but I got the following error. It seems that there is no linking at all to any library I added. I searched on similar problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-) where adding libraries after object files is suggested but that does not solve my problem since this is the order in the original makefile.

```
cc  -I/home/afrah/pdslin/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/afrah/SuperLU_DIST_3.3/SRC -I/usr/local/include -DSCOTCH_ORDER -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/share/parmetis/include   -I/usr/share/mpich-install/include -I/home/afrah/petsc/include -I/home/afrah/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/include -c dtest.c -o dtest.o 
dtest.c: In function ‘main’:
dtest.c:54:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pdslin_print_input’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if ( !proc_id ) pdslin_print_input(&input);
                    ^
dtest.c:125:39: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pdslin_print_stat’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if( input.verbose == PDSLin_VALL ) pdslin_print_stat( &stat, matrix.pdslin_comm );
                                       ^
cc    dtest.o  /usr/lib/libblas.so /usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/share/mpich-install/lib/libmpich.so /usr/share/parmetis/lib/libmetis.a  /usr/local/lib/libparmetis.so /usr/local/lib/libscotch.a   /usr/local/lib/libscotchmetis.a /usr/local/lib/libptscotchparmetis.a  /usr/local/lib/libptscotcherr.a /usr/local/lib/libptscotch.a /home/afrah/SuperLU_DIST_3.3/lib/libsuperlu_dist.so  /home/afrah/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib/libpetsc.so /home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a       -o dtest 
dtest.o: In function `main':
dtest.c:(.text+0xb65): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dtest.c:(.text+0xb88): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dtest.c:(.text+0xbb7): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dtest.c:(.text+0xbda): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dtest.c:(.text+0xc14): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dtest.o:dtest.c:(.text+0xc37): more undefined references to `sqrt' follow
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(pdslin_wrapper.o): In function `pdslin_error_handler':
pdslin_wrapper.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(pdslin_util.o): In function `pdslin_init_input':
pdslin_util.c:(.text+0x1c48): undefined reference to `log10'
pdslin_util.c:(.text+0x1c61): undefined reference to `floor'
pdslin_util.c:(.text+0x1c8b): undefined reference to `pow'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_io.o): In function `dread_matrix':
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x4e4): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_io.o): In function `dread_ijvt':
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x26e3): undefined reference to `dCompRow_to_CompCol_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_io.o): In function `dread_hb':
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x2eac): undefined reference to `dallocateA_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x3101): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x3115): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x3129): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x3281): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x3293): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dpdslin_io.c:(.text+0x32a5): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_util.o): In function `dsort3':
dpdslin_util.c:(.text+0xcbc): undefined reference to `sswap_'
dpdslin_util.c:(.text+0xd07): undefined reference to `dswap_'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_util.o): In function `dgenerate_dblocks':
dpdslin_util.c:(.text+0xe4c): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `dinit_schur_comm':
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x6fd): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `ddistribute_matrix':
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x10d1): undefined reference to `ceil'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x136a): undefined reference to `floor'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x15df): undefined reference to `dCompRow_to_CompCol_dist'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x1b16): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x1ba2): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x1bb2): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x2554): undefined reference to `ceil'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x2913): undefined reference to `ceil'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x2f2e): undefined reference to `ceil'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x3b6b): undefined reference to `ceil'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `dalltoall_matrix':
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x4978): undefined reference to `log10'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x4991): undefined reference to `floor'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x49c3): undefined reference to `pow'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `dallgather_separator':
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x6ad2): undefined reference to `ceil'
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x6b42): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `dalltoall_interface':
dpdslin_dist.c:(.text+0x8cbd): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_dist.o): In function `dget_rowdisp_var':
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x1601): undefined reference to `set_default_options_dist'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x16d5): undefined reference to `sqrt'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x18a1): undefined reference to `ScalePermstructInit'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x18c6): undefined reference to `PStatInit'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x19c2): undefined reference to `dCreate_CompRowLoc_Matrix_dist'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x19d5): undefined reference to `set_default_options_dist'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x1e11): undefined reference to `PStatPrint'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x1f63): undefined reference to `Destroy_SuperMatrix_Store_dist'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x200b): undefined reference to `PStatFree'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_sludist.o): In function `dsolve_interior_superludist':
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x2397): undefined reference to `PStatInit'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x23f7): undefined reference to `pdgssvx'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x240a): undefined reference to `PStatFree'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_sludist.o): In function `dtrisolve_superludist':
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x262b): undefined reference to `PStatInit'
dpdslin_sludist.c:(.text+0x2691): undefined reference to `PStatFree'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpdslin_hls.o): In function `dsolve_interior_hls':
dpdslin_hls.c:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to `ceil'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dschur_sludist.o): In function `dcompG_superludist':
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to `sp_ienv_dist'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0xaca): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0xca2): undefined reference to `floor'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0xede): undefined reference to `floor'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x2b20): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x2f2e): undefined reference to `floor'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x316a): undefined reference to `floor'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x40e6): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x4306): undefined reference to `floor'
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x4542): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dschur_sludist.o): In function `dcompW_superludist':
dschur_sludist.c:(.text+0x54a8): undefined reference to `sp_ienv_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpostorderInterface.o): In function `dpostOrderInterface':
dpostorderInterface.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `isort'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dpostorderInterface.o): In function `dpostOrderBInterface':
dpostorderInterface.c:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to `isort'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(memory.o): In function `pdslin_symbfact_SubInit':
memory.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `sp_ienv_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `SetupSpace'
memory.c:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `user_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x250): undefined reference to `user_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `user_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `user_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x31d): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `user_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(memory.o): In function `pdslin_symbfact_SubXpand':
memory.c:(.text+0x774): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(memory.o): In function `pdslin_symbfact_SubFree':
memory.c:(.text+0x7aa): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x7ba): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(memory.o): In function `pdslin_symbfact_FreeExpanders':
memory.c:(.text+0x7f4): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(memory.o): In function `pdslin_expand':
memory.c:(.text+0x898): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x8b2): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x94d): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x96e): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x9b1): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
memory.c:(.text+0x9ee): undefined reference to `user_malloc_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(slu.o): In function `pdslin_slu_gridmap':
slu.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x37e): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x4d4): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(slu.o): In function `pdslin_destroyU':
slu.c:(.text+0x5cf): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x5ef): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x60b): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(slu.o):slu.c:(.text+0x61b): more undefined references to `superlu_free_dist' follow
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(slu.o): In function `pdslin_allocateUT':
slu.c:(.text+0x829): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x885): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x892): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x8ee): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x8fb): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x957): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x96b): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
slu.c:(.text+0x9c7): undefined reference to 
pdgstrsUT.c:(.text+0x309c): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pdgstrsUT.c:(.text+0x351f): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
pdgstrsUT.c:(.text+0x3d17): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
dslu.c:(.text+0xdd7): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0xf58): undefined reference to `pdgstrs'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1061): undefined reference to `pdlangs'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1077): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x10bf): undefined reference to `pdgsmv_finalize'
dslu.c:(.text+0x10ea): undefined reference to `pdgsmv_init'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1103): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1110): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1159): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1405): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x144e): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x14ee): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1544): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x158e): undefined reference to `pxgstrs_init'
dslu.c:(.text+0x160e): undefined reference to `pdgsrfs'
dslu.c:(.text+0x162b): undefined reference to `pxgstrs_finalize'
dslu.c:(.text+0x163a): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1653): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x16a9): undefined reference to `pdPermute_Dense_Matrix'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1896): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(dslu.o): In function `dpdslin_slu_fact':
dslu.c:(.text+0x1ba2): undefined reference to `pxerbla'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1d4a): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1d93): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1da0): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1de9): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1e1f): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1e68): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1e89): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1ed2): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x1efc): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x22c3): undefined reference to `pdgsequ'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2319): undefined reference to `pdlaqgs'
dslu.c:(.text+0x232d): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x235e): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x238f): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x23df): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2452): undefined reference to `pdCompRow_loc_to_CompCol_global'
dslu.c:(.text+0x24f5): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x25d5): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x261e): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x262b): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2674): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2877): undefined reference to `exp'
dslu.c:(.text+0x28cb): undefined reference to `exp'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2d0d): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2d1c): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2e04): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2eca): undefined reference to `pdlangs'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2eed): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2f66): undefined reference to `log10'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2f7f): undefined reference to `floor'
dslu.c:(.text+0x2fa1): undefined reference to `pow'
dslu.c:(.text+0x3166): undefined reference to `get_perm_c_parmetis'
dslu.c:(.text+0x32bb): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x32fe): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x3352): undefined reference to `sp_colorder'
dslu.c:(.text+0x3475): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
dslu.c:(.text+0x348b): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
dslu.c:(.text+0x3c11): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x526): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x562): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x5c7): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x610): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x62c): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x675): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x689): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x72f): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x80c): undefined reference to `genmmd_dist_'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x861): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x870): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x87f): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x88e): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x89d): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(get_perm_c.o):get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x8ac): more undefined references to `superlu_free_dist' follow
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(get_perm_c.o): In function `get_perm_c_dist_t':
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x8b6): undefined reference to `SuperLU_timer_dist_'
get_perm_c.c:(.text+0x91a): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(symbolic.o): In function `pdslin_symbfact':
symbolic.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x2fd): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x319): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x38b): undefined reference to `sp_ienv_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x3ba): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x43d): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x8fd): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
symbolic.c:(.text+0x916): undefined reference to `ifill_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(symbolic.o): In function `pdslin_column_dfs':
symbolic.c:(.text+0x1021): undefined reference to `sp_ienv_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(symbolic.o): In function `pdslin_pivotL':
symbolic.c:(.text+0x1ae9): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(pdgstrs_init.o): In function `dpdslin_pgstrs_init':
pdgstrs_init.c:(.text+0x3f1): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
pdgstrs_init.c:(.text+0x43a): undefined reference to
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x1de4): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x1e30): undefined reference to `superlu_malloc_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x1e79): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x1e86): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x1ecf): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x2a31): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x2a7a): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x2acd): undefined reference to `doubleMalloc_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x2b2f): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x30dc): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x30eb): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x30fa): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x3109): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x3118): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(pddistribute.o):pddistribute.c:(.text+0x3127): more undefined references to `superlu_free_dist' follow
/home/afrah/pdslin/lib/libhybrid.a(pddistribute.o): In function `dpdslin_pdistribute_base':
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x31e4): undefined reference to `intMalloc_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x3240): undefined reference to `superlu_abort_and_exit_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x326f): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x327e): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
pddistribute.c:(.text+0x328d): undefined reference to `superlu_free_dist'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:10: recipe for target 'dtest' failed
make: *** [dtest] Error 1
```

This is the content of makefile.inc:

```
#
# top directory make.inc
# 
# on hopper: % module load cray-petsc which also loads cray-tpsl, including pt-schotch and parmetis.

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# home directory, where the software is located
TOP  = /home/afrah/pdslin

INCLUDEDIR =/usr/local/include
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# hybrid solver library name
LIB  = $(TOP)/lib/libhybrid.a

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Libraries:
#
# MPI/BLAS libraries
L_MPI =   /usr/share/mpich-install/lib/libmpich.so
I_MPI =  -I/usr/share/mpich-install/include
L_BLAS = /usr/lib/libblas.so /usr/lib/liblapack.so

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make utility
MAKE = make

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# archiver and flags to build the library
ARCH         = /usr/bin/ar
ARCHFLAGS    = cr
RANLIB       = /usr/bin/ranlib
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# C compiler and flags
CC    = /usr/share/mpich-install/bin/mpicc
FLAGS =  -Wall -Wextra
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# fortran compiler and flags
FC     = mpif90
FLIB   = -pgf90libs
FFLAGS = -g 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# linker used to link example program with the library
#LINKER = /usr/share/mpich-install/bin/mpicc -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition

LINKER = $(CC) -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition 

#------------------------------------------------------------------
# C++ compiler (this is not needed for your standard compilation)
CPP = mpicxx

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# for Scotch version 6.0 and higher,include both sequential and parallel
PAR_LIB = /usr/local/lib
L_PPART = $(PAR_LIB)/libparmetis.so \
          $(PAR_LIB)/libscotch.a   $(PAR_LIB)/libscotchmetis.a  \
          $(PAR_LIB)/libptscotchparmetis.a  $(PAR_LIB)/libptscotcherr.a $(PAR_LIB)/libptscotch.a

I_PPART = -I/usr/local/include \
           -DSCOTCH_ORDER -I/usr/local/include

#------------------------------------------------------#
# Metis Library, and its header files
L_METIS =  /usr/share/parmetis/lib/libmetis.a 
I_METIS =  -I/usr/share/parmetis/include 


#------------------------------------------------------#
# SuperLU_DIST library, and its header files  (hopper: module load superlu_dist)
# SLUDIST = /global/common/hopper2/acts/SuperLU/SuperLU_DIST/2.5
# L_SLUDIST = -L$(SLUDIST)/craypgi-xe6_O/lib -lsuperlu_dist_2.5
# I_SLUDIST = -I$(SLUDIST)/SRC 

SLUDIST = /home/afrah/SuperLU_DIST_3.3
I_SLUDIST = -I$(SLUDIST)/SRC
L_SLUDIST =  $(SLUDIST)/lib/libsuperlu_dist.so


#------------------------------------------------------#
# Petsc library, and its header files
# double version
I_PETSC = -I/home/afrah/petsc/include \
          -I/home/afrah/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/include
L_PETSC = /home/afrah/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib/libpetsc.so


#------------------------------------------------------#
# Other optional libraries

# serial SuperLU
#L_SLU = /home/afrah/SuperLU_5.2.0/lib/libsuperlu_5.2.a
#I_SLU = -I/home/afrah/SuperLU_5.2.0/SRC

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# accumulate all includes and libraries

INC  = -I$(TOP)/include -I$(INCLUDEDIR) $(I_SLUDIST) $(I_PPART) $(I_METIS)  $(I_MPI) $(I_PETSC)
LIBS = $(L_BLAS) $(L_MPI) $(L_METIS) $(L_PPART) $(L_SLUDIST)  $(L_PETSC) $(LIB)      
ZLIBS = $(L_BLAS) $(L_MPI) $(L_METIS) $(L_PPART) $(L_SLUDIST)  $(L_PETSC) $(LIB)
```

Some other information:

> mpicc --version gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
>   Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to link against `-lm`.

Comment: `warning: implicit declaration of function...` means that some function declarations were not found by the compiler. Add the missing include directives in your source code and the missing `-I<PATH>` compilation options. `undefined reference to...` means that the linker could not resolve some symbols (`sqrt`, `superlu_free_dist`...) Add the missing `-l<LIB>` options or the missing libraries to link.