# Using C library functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I have been trying to follow this [blog](https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-native/) and I have run all the steps successfully but however when I run the last command

`konanc $COMPILER_ARGS -target macbook src/main/kotlin/logogen.kt -library build/c_interop/png -linkerOpts "-L/usr/local/lib -lpng" -o build/bin/logogen`

I get errors which say sqrt,pow,fopen,fclose are all unresolved

`error: unresolved reference: sqrt`

This is what is in my png.def file

`headers = /usr/local/include/png.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h math.h`

Imported it in my logogen.kt file as

`import png.*`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`compilerOpts = -lm` in the `.def` file shall do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What are you replacing `$COMPILER_ARGS` with? Presumably you pass there the C libraries that define those C references and which are required by your program. For example, for the [sqrt undefined reference you would add '-lm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math/10409061). Same for anything else that the compiler tells you is missing.