# why I am getting "Undefined symbol: .sqrtf" even after Including math.h and linking to math library using -lm

Tags: c++, unix, linker, aix, math.h

when I am tring to compile

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   double m=1.66666;
   double k=sqrtf(m);
   return 0;
}
```

using following command

```
/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/bin/gcc -o test.out test.cpp -lm
```

it throws

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .sqrtf
```

ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
collect2: error: ld returned 8 exit status

But below code compiles successfully

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   double k=sqrtf(1.66666);
   return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc4.8.5 to compile the code ..same code compiles successfully on AIX6.1 but it is failing on new machine(AIX7.1)

Similar question already exist on this: [Why am I getting "undefined reference to sqrt" error even though I include math.h header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math) but it is not working for me.

Update: when I use `sqrt` instead of `sqrtf` code compiles successfully, using command `'/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/bin/gcc -o test.out test.cpp -lm to compile it.`sqrtf` fails with or without linking to math library.

edit2: output of nm command

```
$ nm -g -X32 /usr/lib/libm.a | grep sqrtf
.csqrtf              T         512
csqrtf               D        4196          12

$ nm -g -X64 /usr/lib/libm.a | grep sqrtf
.csqrtf              T         512
csqrtf               D        4296          24
```

edit 3: `bos.adt.libm.7.1.3.47` was installed which doesn't have `sqrtf`. Installed  `bos.adt.libm.7.1.4.30.bff` and it started to work fine.

Comment: Your code is ok, but change "%d" to "%f". https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bfe2wuuplGWQl2RK

Comment: Hahaha not that important in this context.  Ignore the print line. Anyway updated the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Of course, not important ))) But code is ok.

Comment: You might have not installed the package that contains `/usr/lib/libm.a` -- `bos.adt.libm` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install package `bos.adt.libm`. Or ask you system-administrator to do so.

--

Edit: The call of function `sqrtf` in your code might very well be optimized away, as it can be calculated compile-time, also the result is never used. Here is an actual example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    double val, k;

    if (argc>1) val= strtod (argv[1], NULL);
    else        val= 1.66666;

    k=sqrtf (val);
    printf ("val=%g k=%g\n", val, k);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -o sid_math sid_math.c -Wl,-bmap:sid_math.map # fails
gcc -o sid_math sid_math.c -lm -Wl,-bmap:sid_math.map # works
```

--
Edit: also you should examine the content of `libma.a`, eg:

```
$ nm -g -X32 /usr/lib/libm.a | grep sqrtf
.csqrtf              T         512
csqrtf               D        4132          12
.sqrtf               T         480
sqrtf                D        6364          12

$ nm -g -X64 /usr/lib/libm.a | grep sqrtf
.csqrtf              T         512
csqrtf               D        4232          24
.sqrtf               T         480
sqrtf                D        6616          24
```

Comment: `bos.adt.libm` package is already Installed.  when I run following command `lslpp -l | grep bos.adt.libm `.  I get ` bos.adt.libm              7.1.4.0  COMMITTED  Base Application Development`.                                                                                         
     I can see **usr/lib/libm.a** present on my system.

Comment: one update: when I use `sqrt` instead of `sqrtf` code compiles successfully. when I use the command '/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/bin/gcc -o test.out test.cpp -lm` to compile it. `sqrtf` fails with or without linking to math library.

Comment: Report the bug to your AIX-vendor.

Comment: Thank you!! Installing latest `bos.adt.libm` solved the problem.