# Debug c program on vscode,launch:Program '.../.../.../coding' does not exist

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've debugged it many times and there was no problem.I don't know why there's this problem now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laV1n.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTWmj.png)

Comment: It does not exist because the build failed because of the linker error.

Comment: Your error seems to be this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math)

Comment: Check your `tasks.json`

Comment: I just pressed F5 to debug . I saw that answer and he compiled with gcc test.c -o test -lm ,how do I debug this in vscode?What step should I do before press F5?

Comment: Make sure your build task in tasks.json uses the correct libraries.

Comment: "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],  should I add "-lm" here?

Comment: Yes add it as an argument.

Comment: Solved,thank you very much