# I am fairly new to code blocks.I have spent too much time on this error .Can someone point out what is my mistake in this code

Tags: c, codeblocks, math.h

I am new to codeblocks. I was trying to find height of a BST and used `max()` function. But while compiling CodeBlock throws error.I am using Windows machine.I know linking maths.h manually will solve the issue.I know how to link math.h manually using gcc but i dont know gcc equivalent for windows.Basically i want to know is there any other solution besides linking??If manually linking is the only option left then how to do it on Windows on CodeBlocks.Thank you!!

> undefined reference to max

I am pretty sure there is no error in logic all import statements are correct too. But still no output!! Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

//Definition of Node for Binary search tree
struct BstNode {
    int data;
    struct BstNode* left;
    struct BstNode* right;
};
struct BstNode* GetNewNode(int);
struct BstNode* Insert(struct BstNode*,int );
int findHeight(struct BstNode *);
//struct BstNode* findMin(struct BstNode* root)
// Function to create a new Node in heap
struct BstNode* GetNewNode(int data) {
    struct BstNode* newNode = (struct BstNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct BstNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// To insert data in BST, returns address of root node
struct BstNode* Insert(struct BstNode* root,int data) {//pass by value therefore * used and reurn stmt.otherwise pbarg ** no return
    if(root == NULL) { // empty tree
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    // if data to be inserted is lesser, insert in left subtree.
    else if(data <= root->data) {
        root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    // else, insert in right subtree.
    else {
        root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}
int findHeight(struct BstNode * root){
    if(root=NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return max(findHeight(root->left),findHeight(root->right))+1;
    }

};
//BstNode* findMin(BstNode* root)
int main() {
    int a,b;
    struct BstNode* root = NULL;  // Creating an empty tree
    /*Code to test the logic*/
    root = Insert(root,15);
    root = Insert(root,10);
    root = Insert(root,20);
    root = Insert(root,25);
    root = Insert(root,8);
    root = Insert(root,12);
findHeight(root);
}
```

Comment: what is the error it gives you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - undefined reference to sqrt (or other mathematical functions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248919/c-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-or-other-mathematical-functions)

Comment: Where have you heard about a max() function? There's not such thing in `math.h`

Comment: i thought it was predefined inside math.h lib like sqrt()??Correct me if i am wrong :/

Comment: `grep max  /usr/include/math.h` yelds nothing. `apropos max` neither. You have to implement your max() func.

Comment: @user3847870 I haven't seen a standard `max` function. Just use an `if` statement to get the maximum instead or implement your own `max` function as @jbm suggests

Comment: There is `fmax` only: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.12.2

Comment: @jbm@Cool Guy sorry guys.You are right!!.There is not max() in math.h.Got confused jumping back to c after high lvl languages.Thank you for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't declare `max` function.
2. In `findHeight` function you did `if(root=NULL)` which should have been `if(root==NULL)`. Do it like this:

   ```
   int findHeight(struct BstNode * root){
       if(root==NULL){
           return -1;
       } else {
           return max(findHeight(root->left),findHeight(root->right))+1;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to print the value of the `findHeight`.

Comment: Worked!!!!So silly mistake.I came back to C after working on python and it all got messed up.I thought max() was built in function in C too .Thanks man!! All this time i thought problem was in recursion .Never thought it would be an assignment operator.Thanks again!!!!

Comment: I can understand your feeling because it also happened to me once when i came back to **C++** after spending  lot of my time with **R**.