# why is it showing errors like ld returned 1 exit status and undefined reference to `powr(int, int)'

Tags: c, dev-c++

why is it showing errors like ld returned 1 exit status and undefined reference to `powr(int, int)'

```
#include<stdio.h>

int powr (int m , int n );
int main (){

     int i,m,n;
     printf("print the base\n");
     scanf("%d",&m);
     printf("print the expoenent\n");
     scanf("%d",&n);

     int p ;
     if (n == 1 ){
        return m;
     }
     else {
        p = powr(m,n/2);
        if (n%2 ==0 ){
            return p*p ;

         }
         else {
            return p*p*m;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - undefined reference to sqrt (or other mathematical functions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248919/c-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-or-other-mathematical-functions)

Comment: There ain't no standard function `powr(int, int)` in C. Did you mean `pow(double, double)` from `math.h`?

Comment: You put a prototype of `powr` function but you mentioned no where its definition in the question. Can't say anything without seeing the definition.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the `pow` function which returns the power of two numbers.

Because `pow` is in `math.h`. So include it:

```
#include <math.h>
```

And while compiling it, link `math.h`:

```
gcc program.c -lm
```

`-lm` is linking it to the `math.h` library.

Also see: [C - undefined reference to sqrt (or other mathematical functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248951/5735775)

Comment: I think he wants to write a power function instead of using existing one.

Comment: @haccks, um, are you sure? I don't think so. I'll try making one, and post it. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have to **define** your function powr in your code just declaring it will not help.