# Show error to run code while using pow function in VS Code

Tags: c

When I am going to run a simple code by using pow function terminal of VS Code showing error. Essentially, I've to write a program that, amongst other things, calculates the area of a square from a given side. I thought I'd use the `pow()` function rather than simply using `side * side`, but the compiler keeps giving me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEMiotv.o: in function `main':
area_square.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `pow' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code looks like the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {
     //calculate area of a square
     double side, area;
     printf("Enter the value of side of square: ");
     scanf("%.2lf", &side);
     area = pow(side,2);
     printf("The area of square is %.2lf", area);
     return 0; }
```

And I'm compiling with the command:

`gcc area_square.c`

What can I do to resolve the problem please suggest me something. Any thoughts would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: The `pow` function is in the math library `m`. To add a library you use the `-l` option. Like `-lm`. Not that you actually *need* the `pow` function. As basic math should have taught you, anything to the power of two is the same as the value multiplied by itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to sqrt (or other mathematical functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248919/undefined-reference-to-sqrt-or-other-mathematical-functions)

Comment: On a different note, if you're using GCC to build, why did you add the Clang tag? Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Hint: when you see `/usr/bin/ld` in the errors, it means your compilation has succeeded (enable warnings!) but that the error is in the _linking_ stage. This can help more quickly point you to solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -o area_square area_square.c -lm
```

Try the above command for compiling as it links the math library.
Also use %lf instead of %.2lf in scanf

Comment: Your code doesn't show any errors but it also not run in the terminal.

Comment: @AyanBanerjee what does that mean? This command only builds the executable. It does not run it. You need to run the program afterwards.

Comment: when I run it show the same thing again bro. can you please tell me did I need to setup some thing before using the pow function