# What does -lm option do in g++?

Tags: gcc, g++

What does `-lm` option do in g++ and when is it needed?

Is there a complete description of g++ options?

Comment: There's a complete list in GCC's documentation (man gcc).

Comment: Duplicate of [sqrt from math.h causes compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711915/sqrt-from-math-h-causes-compile-error). Also related to [gcc: why the -lm flag is needed to link the math library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606301/gcc-why-the-lm-flag-is-needed-to-link-the-math-library)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I'm Getting "undefined reference to `sqrt' " Error, Even Though I include math.h header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-im-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-ma)

Comment: Why does my g++ compile without it?(at least this part is not duplicate)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a linker option. It tells the linker to link with (`-l`) the `m` library (libm.so/dll). That's the math library. You often need it if you `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: i was using #include<math> and getting math not found. Changing it to #include<math.h> resolved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

The option does nothing for `g++`: referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033940/1143274 `libstdc++` requires `libm`, so it will always be linked by **`g++`**.

However, there is also some sort of an automatic linking behaviour for `gcc`, investigated on this thread http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/125526-c-gcc-math-h-lm.html which I can't seem to find an answer as to where that comes from and which libraries it applies to...