# How to link Armadillo with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, linker, armadillo

I want to use Armadillo with Eclipse. However all the instructions to link Armadillo is given for Visual Studio. Now I followed the instructions outlined in the ReadMe file of the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html). I added the Armadillo include folder in `project(right click)->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross G++ Compiler->Includes->Inlcude paths(-I)` and then I added the libraries folder (The library folder contain lapack and blas .lib and .dll files) in `project(right click)->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross G++ Linker->Libraries->Library search path (-L)`.

However when I compile the code in the Eclipse I get the error

> .....armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:37: undefined reference to `dgetrf_'.

Shouldn't it simply search for .lib files in the library folder and include them during compiling? I would appreciate any help regarding this matter.

Regards,
TM

Answer (score 2):

Linking the Armadillo library to an Eclipse project can be done and you were about to do it ! It's pretty much the same as for any other library.

In the properties of the project :

- GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes : add the path to the file `armadillo` (where namespace `arma` is declared) to the include search path (option -I). Example : `/home/alpha/soft/armadillo-4.400.1/include`
- GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries : add the path to the file `libarmadillo.so...` in the library search path (option -L) Example : `/home/alpha/soft/armadillo-4.400.1` . Add `armadillo`, `lapack`, `blas` and `m` as libraries (option -l). [`m` is for math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447791/what-does-lm-option-do-in-g).

Here are the calls to the compiler and the linker as produced by eclipse :

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/armaeclip.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/alpha/soft/armadillo-4.100.1/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/armaeclip.d" -MT"src/armaeclip.d" -o "src/armaeclip.o" "../src/armaeclip.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/armaeclip.cpp



Building target: armaeclip
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/alpha/soft/armadillo-4.100.1 -o "armaeclip" ./src/armaeclip.o   -larmadillo -lblas -lm -llapack
Finished building target: armaeclip
**** Build Finished ****
```

As you run the code, you might get something like :

> error: det(): use of ATLAS or LAPACK needs to be enabled
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>     what():  det(): use of ATLAS or LAPACK needs to be enabled
>   Abandon (core dumped)

To avoid this problem, follow the advise of the [faq of Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) : uncomment `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` in file `/home/alpha/soft/armadillo-4.100.1/include/config.hpp` and rebuild your project.

Comment: Hi Francis, Thank you for the advise. However I don't have .so files of lapack, blas, m or armadillo. The only library files I have are of the form lapack_WIN64_MT.lib and blas_WIN64_MT.lib. When I link the Armadillo folder and add lapack and blas as libraries I get the error "cannot find lapack and blas" So I am assuming I am missing .so files but where can I find them?

Comment: Could you try to add `lapack_WIN64_MT`  and `blas_WIN64_MT` as libraries instead of `lapack` and `blas` ? According to the [naming convention of MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use), it might solve your problem.

Comment: I tried but it reads cannot find lapack_WIN64_MT and cannot find blas_WIN64_MT. I kind of gave up and using Eigen Liner Algebra Library

Comment: @francis It still works perfectly! Thank you! You should add "Add only the text "armadillo", "lapack", "blas" and "m" at libraries (option -l)". Got very confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create GNU `Autotools` projects and add following line:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=armadillo_example
armadillo_example_SOURCES=armadillo_example.cpp
armadillo_example_LDADD=-larmadillo
```

To `Makefile.am` file where your source code exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require optimized BLAS libraries, you can use the BLAS and LAPACK libraries that come with Armadillo.

1. Project properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler >
   Includes > Include paths (-l): `C:\armadillo-x.xxx.x\include`
2. Then in Environment Variables > System variables, modify the Path
   variable and add: `C:\armadillo-x.xxx.x\examples\lib_win64\`
3. Project properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries:
   `blas_win64_MT` and `lapack_win64_MT` (it is important to add them
   this way, with no path or .lib/.dll)
4. Then in Environment Variables > System variables, modify the Path
   variable and add: `C:\armadillo-x.xxx.x\examples\lib_win64\`

And your Armadillo library in Eclipse is good to go.

I've used Eclipse 4.14.0 and Armadillo 9.850.1.