# Setting up Armadillo c++ in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, armadillo

I am trying to setup Armadillo in my c++ project. I have previolsy used codeblocks, but Now I want to use eclispse. I create a new project in eclipse, and I link to the openblas and lapack libs and include folder, and I have put the .dll files in the same folder as the executable. It works fine when I just make a simple helloworld.cpp file, but when I copy over a bunch of other .cpp and .h (sourse and header-files from my project from codeblocks) into my project, I get this error:

> src\BallJoint.o: In function `gemv<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:34: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemv_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `asum<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:239: undefined reference to`wrapper_dasum_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `nrm2<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:271: undefined reference to`wrapper_dnrm2_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `getrf<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:37: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgetrf_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `gesdd<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:583: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgesdd_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `gesv<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:643: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgesv_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `gels<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:677: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgels_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `getri<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:71: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgetri_'
>   src\DombsMain.o: In function `gemm<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:69: undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemm_'
>   src\RotationMatrix.o: In function `syrk<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:104: undefined reference to`wrapper_dsyrk_'
>   src\RotationMatrix.o: In function `dot<double>':
>   C:/Users/elias/Documents/eclipseCPP_test2/dombs/include/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:183: undefined reference to`wrapper_ddot_'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What could be causing this?

**Edit**

I made a new project and tried this code, and I get the same error. The code

```
arma::mat mm, mm2;
mm <<1<<1<<1;
mm2 <<1<<1<<1;
arma::mat mm3 = mm.t() * mm2;
mm3.print("h");
```

So it complains about the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Are you sure you're linking against armadillo itself?

Comment: @ChristianBlume I am new to c++, so I dont really know what linking really does. How do i "link to armadillo itself"?

Comment: Did you link Armadillo properly? Have a look at this website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494610/how-to-link-armadillo-with-eclipse

Comment: @kass I seem to have the same problem as the guy you linked to. Unfortunately they did not seem to solve the problem. I have told eclipse where to find the lib and include folder, but I get the error as  in my post. The answers to the post you linked to talks about .so files, but I dont have any .so files, and I dont know what they do.