# Eclipse IDE fails to compile with Armadillo

Tags: c++, eclipse, armadillo, mingw-w64

I have integrated Armadillo into my working environment, following the steps as listed here: 
[How to link Armadillo with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494610/how-to-link-armadillo-with-eclipse)

I am trying to run this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    mat A = randu<mat>(4, 5);
    mat B = randu<mat>(4, 5);
    cout << A*B.t() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with the Mingw G++ compiler and everytime I get the following error:

```
 ***20:45:00 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Trying Armadillo     ****
 Info: Internal Builder is used for build
 g++ "-ID:\\C++ Development\\armadillo-7.800.0\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o TryNow.o "..\\TryNow.cpp" 
 g++ "-LD:\\C++ Development\\armadillo-7.800.0\\examples\\lib_win64" -o "Trying Armadillo.exe" TryNow.o -llapack_win64_MT -lblas_win64_MT 
 D:\C++ Development\armadillo-7.800.0\examples\lib_win64/blas_win64_MT.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status***
```

The same library works wonderfully with the Microsoft Visual Studio, 2015. Is it an eclipse issue that is bugging me?

Comment: "blas_win64_MT.lib" Looks like you are loading visual studio libraries into the GCC linker backing Eclipse. Solution: Recompile library for GCC or find precompiled GCC library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response. I started with C++ a couple of days back and wish to know how to compile a library with gcc. Thanks.

Comment: Ayyyiii. That can be a tough one for a complex software project. For Armadillo hope the writers give you instructions or a build script.

Comment: Get the precompiled version from the [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) project -- see the Binary Packages section. It's a very fast version of both BLAS and LAPACK. I think they compile it with MinGW.