# main.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `sqrt'

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why I get this error when I try to compile my program in gcc. I have included the math library. I have included `-lm`. Is there something wrong with my compiler?

```
$ gcc -lm -Wall *.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/ccqqxFDD.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int x1 = 5;
    int x2 = 7;
    int y1 = 11;
    int y2 = 8;    
    double distance = 0; 
    distance=sqrt((pow((x2- x1), 2))+(pow((y2 - y1), 2)));
    printf(" distance is: %lf \n", distance);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put the libraries after the source files :-
gcc -Wall *.c -lm so that it knows what symbols to look for that are missing to resolve

Comment: Try compiling a minimal program: `#include <math.h> \n int main() { sqrt(3.0); return 0; }` and see if it reproduces the problem.

Comment: We really need to see some code/source, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqrt from math.h causes compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711915/sqrt-from-math-h-causes-compile-error)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something wrong with my compiler?

No.

> I have included `-lm`.

This is not enough, You also need respect order of options:

`$ gcc -Wall *.c -lm`

According to the
`man gсс`

> ...
>   You can mix options and other arguments.  For the most part, the order you use doesn't matter.  Order does matter when you use
>   several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L more
>   than once, the directories are searched in the order specified.  **Also, the placement of the -l option is significant.**
>   ...
>   -llibrary
>   ...
>   **It makes a difference where in the command you write this option**; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.
>   ...